# PyMongo and Mongodb: using update()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, insert-update

I am trying to use pymongo to update an existing index:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.alfmonitor
tests = db.tests

post = {
    'name' : 'Blah',
    'active' : True,
    'url' : 'http://www.google.com',
}

tests.insert(post)

tests_list = db.tests.find({'active':True, 'name':'Blah'})
for test in tests_list:
    test['active'] = False
    test.update(
        test,
    )

print '===================================================='

for test in db.tests.find():
    print test #<- when I print out these, active=True is still showing up
```

I've been trying to follow documentation and examples I have seen on SO but none of them seem to be working for me. Anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this (don't forget to add `multi=True` if you want to update **all** matches):

`db.tests.update({'active':True, 'name':'Blah'}, {'$set': {'active': False}}, multi=True)`

Why your code isn't working:

```
for test in tests_list:
    # test is of a dict type
    test['active'] = False
    # You are calling the method of dict type
    # that adds all values from dictionary test to dictionary test,
    # so nothing goes to database
    test.update(
        test,
    )
```

Comment: When I tried this I got:

{u'active': False, u'url': u'http://www.google.com', u'_id': ObjectId('53417509399f808d4929697e'), u'name': u'Blah'}
{u'active': True, u'url': u'http://www.google.com', u'_id': ObjectId('53417552399f808d55c4e74b'), u'name': u'Blah'}

It doesn't appear to be updating all of them that fit the query.

Comment: Still getting the same thing.

Comment: @jnoob you didn't specify `multi=True`

Comment: Hey Traceur, the multi=True did the trick :) Thanks very much for the explanation and patience :)

Comment: @jnoob No problem :). You should also accept the answer if you find it helpful and comprehensive. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is how.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these worked for me:

```
db.tests.update(
    {'active':True, 'name':'Blah'}, 
    {
        '$set': {'active': False}
    },
    multi=True
)


tests_list = db.tests.find({'active':True, 'name':'Blah'})
for test in tests_list:
    test['active'] = False
    db.tests.save(test)
```

Thanks very much traceur and JonnyHK!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to commit changes made to a retrieved doc, use [`collection.save`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.save) instead of `update`:

```
test['active'] = False
db.tests.save(test)
```

Comment: If I use this, where do I tell it to change 'active' from True to False?

Comment: This one works when you do:

    tests_list = db.tests.find({'active':True, 'name':'Blah'})
    for test in tests_list:
        test['active'] = False
        db.tests.save(test)

Thanks very much for the help on this one as well :)